# Next.js and ag-grid - ResizeObserver.observe error while trying to render client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ag-grid

I have a product page which consists of a searchbar component and a grid component containing the `ag-grid` import and setup.

Simplified the product page looks something like this:

```js
// Dynamic import for client side rendering
const ProductGrid = dynamic(() => import('../modules/products/gridComponent'), {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p>...</p>
})
const Searchbar = dynamic(() => import('../modules/common/Searchbar'), {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p>...</p>
})

const Products = () => {

    // State
    const containerStyle = useMemo(() => ({ width: '100%', height: '100%' }), []);
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
    const [searchLimit, setSearchLimit] = useState(5);
    // Custom hook to fetch from API (has useEffect with searchQuery and searchLimit as dependencies)
    const [ rowData, gridRef, error ] = useDolibarrProducts(searchQuery, searchLimit);

    const updateProducts = useCallback((event) => {
        // Updates product list
        event.preventDefault();
        const query = event.target.elements.search.value;
        setSearchQuery(query);
        setSearchLimit(100);
    }, []);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Searchbar handleSubmit={(event) => updateProducts(event)} />
            <div style={containerStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine-dark">
                <ProductGrid gridRef={gridRef} rowData={rowData} />
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default Products;
```

And the grid component looks like this:

```js
import {AgGridReact} from "ag-grid-react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

// I'm guessing using dynamic to import loadingComponent (a simple custom loading screen) serves no purpose here since gridComponent is already imported dynamically, but I've tried every scenario just in case
const loadingComponent = dynamic( () => import('./loadingComponent'), {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p>...</p>
})

const GridComponent = (props) => {
    const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
        return {
            flex: 1,
            // make every column use 'text' filter by default
            filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
            // enable floating filters by default
            floatingFilter: true,
            // make columns resizable
            resizable: true,
            // enable sorting
            sortable: true,
        };
    }, []);

    const [columnDefs] = useState([
        { field: "label" },
        { field: "ref", headerName: "Reference" },
        {
            field: "price",
            headerName: "Price (€)",
            filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
            filterParams: floatFilter,
            valueFormatter: priceFormatter,
        },
        {
            field: "stock",
            filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
            cellRenderer: stockRenderer
        },
        {
            field: "action",
            cellRenderer: actionRender,
            floatingFilter: false,
            sortable: false,
            filter: false,
        }
    ]);

    const loadingOverlayComponent = useMemo(() => {
        return loadingComponent;
    }, []);


    return (
        <Fragment>
            <AgGridReact
                ref={props.gridRef}
                rowData={props.rowData}
                columnDefs={columnDefs}
                defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
                loadingOverlayComponent={loadingOverlayComponent}
            />
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default GridComponent;
```

**Problem:**

When using this same structure without next.js (client side, without the dynamic imports), the page and components work fine.

However when I try to move to next.js the `ag-grid-community` library leads to an `Unhandled Runtime Error` - `TypeError: ResizeObserver.observe: Argument 1 is not an object.`
Now `ResizeObserver` seems to be a browser function which would explain why ag-grid doesn't work with server side rendering, so that's why I imported the grid component with `dynamic` so that it would render on the client side, yet the issue remains. I'm not sure what I might've missed, but my components seem to work on the client side without next.js but not on the client side when using next.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Turns out the issue was not `ag-grid` conflicting with Next.js but rather `ag-grid` conflicting with React 18.

Turns out React 18 introduced a new render syntax, my issue stem from `npx create-react-app` using the old syntax when I used it to build a quick project for testing.

When the old syntax is used, React will act as if it's running React 17, that is the reason why the conflicts between `ag-grid` and React 18 were not showing when I was not using Next.

As per https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/5090 it seems the issue is now being fixed.